# How to use tidy to indent vueJS HTML5 without breaking/removing part of it

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, tidy

Running tidy on this VueJS code completely break it:

The source VueJS HTML code:

```html
$ cat sample_vue.html
...
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="task in tasks">
          <td><strong>{{task.title}}</strong></td>
          <td>{{task.description}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2'
            @click="delTasks_button(task);"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'edit', params: {id: task.id}}" class="btn
            btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2"><i class="fa
            fa-pencil"></i></router-link>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

I run tidy on it:

```bash
$ tidy -i --custom-tags blocklevel --doctype omit   \
       --show-body-only yes --indent-attributes yes \
       --show-warnings no -q sample_vue.html
```

We get this:

```html
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="task in tasks">
            <td><strong>{{task.title}}</strong></td>
            <td>{{task.description}}</td>
            <td>
              <router-link class=
              "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2"></router-link>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

As you can see the `<button` is removed and the `:to=` and the inner `<i >` also ;(

If I avoid to use the shorten `:to=` syntax for `v-bind:to=` the `v-bind:to=` is preserved but **the global result style broken**:

So from this (with the full `v-bind:to=` syntax):

```html
    <table class='table table-striped'>
      <thead>
        <tr class="table-dark">
          <td scope='col'>title</td>
          <td scope='col'>description</td>
          <td scope='col'>action</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="task in tasks">
          <td><strong>{{task.title}}</strong></td>
          <td>{{task.description}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2'
            @click="delTasks_button(task);"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
            <router-link b-bind:to="{ name: 'edit', params: {id: task.id}}" class="btn
            btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2"><i class="fa
            fa-pencil"></i></router-link>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

We still get a broken output `<button` removed and inner `<i>` removed:

```html
<table class='table table-striped'>
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-dark">
      <td scope='col'>title</td>
      <td scope='col'>description</td>
      <td scope='col'>action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="task in tasks">
      <td><strong>{{task.title}}</strong></td>
      <td>{{task.description}}</td>
      <td>
        <router-link b-bind:to=
        "{ name: 'edit', params: {id: task.id}}"
                     class=
                     "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2">
                     </router-link>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with Tidy?

Comment: Side note: the classes for the `<button>` are wrapped with small quotes; at least for consistency make it double-quotes?

Comment: Tidy has so many option perhaps I don't get the right combo; about single quote for button argument the idea is to have tidy indent real live messy HTML

Comment: Tidy looks like ancient stuff, if I'm seeing the right thing. Are you using an IDE of some kind? Most IDE's offer built-in features to clean code. After that, something like Prettier would be used.

Comment: no IDE my side, I use vim with this line in .vimrc: `au FileType html set equalprg=tidy\ -i\ --custom-tags\ blocklevel\ --doctype\ omit\ --show-body-only\ yes\ --indent-attributes\ yes\ --show-warnings\ no\ --drop-empty-elements\ no\ -w\ 120\  -q`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution for `@click` neither for `:to=` but if we replace them by the no

shortcut VueJS syntax `v-on:click=` and `v-bind:to=` then with this tidy options:

```bash
$ tidy -i --custom-tags blocklevel --doctype omit   \
       --show-body-only yes --indent-attributes yes \
       --show-warnings no 
       --drop-empty-elements no
       -q sample_vue.html
```

we get from this input:

```html
$ cat sample_vue.html
    <table class='table table-striped'>
      <thead>
        <tr class="table-dark">
          <td scope='col'>title</td>
          <td scope='col'>description</td>
          <td scope='col'>action</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="task in tasks">
          <td><strong>{{task.title}}</strong></td>
          <td>{{task.description}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2'
            v-on:click="delTasks_button(task);"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
            <router-link b-bind:to="{ name: 'edit', params: {id: task.id}}" class="btn
            btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2"><i class="fa
            fa-pencil"></i></router-link>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

We get this result (hugly indentation but not parts missing):

```html
<table class='table table-striped'>
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-dark">
      <td scope='col'>title</td>
      <td scope='col'>description</td>
      <td scope='col'>action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="task in tasks">
      <td><strong>{{task.title}}</strong></td>
      <td>{{task.description}}</td>
      <td>
        <button class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2'
            v-on:click="delTasks_button(task);"><i class=
            "fa fa-remove"></i></button>
        <router-link b-bind:to=
        "{ name: 'edit', params: {id: task.id}}"
                     class=
                     "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 mb-2">
                     <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></router-link>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: we are getting closed with "--drop-empty-elements no" good catch